# Prove $\frac{d}{dt} g(t) \le |\gamma'(t)| $

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be an Riemannian manifold, assume there is a smooth curve $\gamma(t)$ starting at point $p$ at time $0$, denote $d(\gamma(t),p) = g(t)$ be the distance of $\gamma(t)$ and $p$, is it possible to get? $$\frac{d}{dt} g(t) \le |\gamma'(t)| \tag{*}$$

---

I consider the case in $\Bbb{R}^n$ which is clear at nice point since $$\frac{d}{dt}|\gamma| = \frac{\gamma\cdot \dot{\gamma}}{|\gamma|}\le |\dot\gamma|$$ as desired, is there some good way to get (*)?

Comment: Is $\gamma$ the above mentioned smooth curve starting at $p$ at time $0$, or is it another curve?

Comment: Yeah is the same curve. it differentiate the inequality I don't have idea, even if it's true? @Didier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $t \geq 0$. For $h \geq 0$,
$$g(t + h) \leq g(t) + \int_{t}^{t + h}|\gamma'(s)|\,ds.$$
Thus if $g'(t)$ exists, $g'(t) \leq |\gamma'(t)|$.